# How to get the root url at startup in an OWIN asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have found many posts very similar to this, but I didn't find any that worked for me.

I have an asp.net Web Api2 (not vnext) application, running under IIS, and using the Owin Startup class.

When installed, the root url to this will be something like

```
http://localhost/appvirtualdirectory
```

where `appvirtualdirectory` is the name of the virtual directory it is configured to run under in IIS.

IS there a way at *startup* where I have no Request property, ie in the `Startup.Configure` method, to get the root URL *including* the virtual directory being used?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath
```

This is valid in both global and owin startup

More details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That only includes the path, not the domain.

Answer (score -2):

I would use:

```
//you have some options but i will show you the easiest
var request = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Request;
var path =  request.Scheme +
              Uri.SchemeDelimiter +
              request.Host +
              request.PathBase;
```

Info about the properties I'm referencing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owinrequest(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Nope: "No owin.Environment item was found in the context." when trying to retrieve the request.